# Cannot Select 'Input line or polygon vector layer' when trying to simplify Shapefile

Tags: qgis, simplify

I'm trying to simplify a Shapefile by opening it in QGIS, Go to the Vector menu, selecting Geometry tools, and selecting Simplify Geometries...

When I do this I get a modal window that I can fill out completely except the very first menu titled 'Input line or polygon vector layer.'

Can anyone help me understand why this might be? [image: modal]

Comment: The title of the tool you have in screen capture is "Extract nodes". Did you add a wrong image to your question?

Comment: No, this is the modal I get when selecting Simplify Geometries. Can you show me what yours looks like when you select the same option?

Comment: "Simplify geometries" as in the answer by @Kurt. If you still get "Extract nodes" by selecting the simplify tool I suggest you to re-install QGIS.

Comment: So I was able to get the right modal to come up (updated image above) now but I still nothing happens when I click the drop down below 'Input line or polygon layer.' Consequently I still cannot perform a simplify action.

Comment: All the vector layers which have been added to the map and which are either lines or polygons should appear in the drop down menu. Do you have such layers in your map?

Comment: Yes. Here is one of the shapefiles I'm trying to simplify: http://cl.ly/cDUk.

Answer (score 1):

as user30184 told you: It looks like you did select "extract nodes". selecting "simplify geometry" you should see something like this (my screenshot is from windows);
[image]

Comment: So I was able to get the right modal to come up now but I still nothing happens when I click the drop down below 'Input line or polygon layer.'

Consequently I still cannot perform a simplify action.

Comment: Have you added  any vector layer to the canvas?

Comment: I opened a shapefile. Does that count as adding a vector layer?

Comment: yes. strange - you should be  able to use this line or ply shape for simplifying or is your shapefile a point.file????

Comment: I'm not sure. Here is one of the files I am trying: http://cl.ly/cDUk.

Comment: this sample is a point-shape-file (with more than 26 000 points). you cant use simplify geometry with points files, therefore you cant "open" it in the dialog-box

Comment: How do I get this into a shapefile with less than 10,000 polygons? This is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: You have points not polygons

Comment: Maybe this is useful  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=iWbYJwu9i5w??

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try opening the original shape file, then save it with another file name, then open that file to see if you are able to choose it for editing.

I have had issues in the past with trying to edit the original shape file.